# ES6 inherited function returns wrong type when invoked on subclass

Tags: static-analysis, return-type, es6-class, ts-check

When a function is inherited by a subclass, I want the return type to be as if the function were defined directly on the subclass.

To be clear, the code works fine at run-time.  But I want to take advantage of static type-checking.  I'm getting red squiggly lines in VScode and warnings from Google-Closure-Compiler.  I'm not sure if this is an issue with my ES6 code or with my type annotations.

My trivial example ES6 classes:

```js
// @ts-check
"use strict";

export class db_row {
    /**
     * @param {number} id 
     */
    constructor(id) {
        /** @type {number} */
        this.id = id;
    }
    clone() {
        return new db_row(this.id);
    }
}

export class Channel_row extends db_row {
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param {*=} init
     * @param {string=} name
     * @param {string=} value
     */
    constructor(init, name, value = '') {
        let id = -1;
        if (typeof init == 'object') {
            id = init.id;
            name = init.name;
            value = init.value;
        } else if (typeof init == 'number') {
            id = init;
        }
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
    clone() {
        return new Channel_row(this.id, this.name, this.value);
    }
}

export class db_table {
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param {Array<db_row>} table 
     */
    constructor(table) {
        /**@type {Array<db_row>} */
        this.table = table;
    }
    /**
     */
    get_table_copy() { return this.table.map(item => item.clone()) }
    /**
     * @param {?number=} id 
     */
    get_row_by_id(id) {
        const row = this.table.filter(item => item.id === id)[0];
        if (row) return row.clone();
        return null;
    }
}

export class Channel_table extends db_table {
    constructor() {
        /**@type {Array<Channel_row>} */
        let table = [];
        super(table);
    }
}
```

```js
// Test code below:
/**
 * 
 * @param {Channel_row} chan_row 
 */
function print_chan_row(chan_row) {
    console.log(chan_row.name);
}

let channel_table = new Channel_table();

let channel_row = channel_table.get_row_by_id(0); // hover reports that the type of channel_row is db_row, when it should be type Channel_row

print_chan_row(channel_row); // Red squiggly line error: Argument of type 'db_row' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Channel_row'.   Type 'db_row' is missing the following properties from type 'Channel_row': name, valuets(2345)

console.log(channel_row.name);  // Red squiggly line error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'db_row'.ts(2339)

let channel_table_2 = channel_table.get_table_copy(); // hover reports that the type of channel_row is db_row[], when it should be type Channel_row[]

print_chan_row(channel_table_2[0]); // Red squiggly line error: Argument of type 'db_row' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Channel_row'.ts(2345)
```

Now, if I move or copy the get_row_by_id() and get_table_copy() functions into the subclass, the type errors go away.  But I don't want to duplicate code unnecessarily.

How can I declare the functions in the parent class so it can be reused in child classes, but maintain the static type checking?

As a bonus, can I also generalize the clone() function so it doesn't need to be over-ridden in subclasses of db_row?

Comment: Are you asking about an IDE feature (highlights or warnings in your IDE) or a TypeScript feature or a Javascript feature?  I'm confused.

Comment: I'm not using TypeScript (maybe I should be?).  I'm writing in ES6 and transpiling to ES5 with Google-Closure-Compiler.  My type annotations are in jsdoc comments.  The @ts-check flag gives me static checking in VScode which is a life saver!

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Are you asking about something you want VSCode to show you that it isn't?  Or are you asking about an ES6 programming proiblem?

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't know the answer to that.  I guess it is either a bug in the static analysis provided by VSCode, or I've written some incorrect ES6 code.

Comment: /**
     * @returns {Channel_row[]}
     */
    get_table_copy() {
        return super.get_table_copy();
    }  -- this makes the types happy, but still seems unnecessary.

Comment: In typescript you would use a generic class to specific the type of the rows. I don't know if JSDoc has anything like that.  Ultimately what's happening is that `super(table)` requires a `db_row` array and doesn't care about anything beyond that.  `Channel_row` is a `db_row`, so calling `super(table)` with them is fine.  But `super` just sees them as `db_row`.

Comment: [this is what it looks like in typescript](https://tsplay.dev/KN7dEm)

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste for the example.  It will be helpful when I (someday) migrate my code to TypeScript .